# Assign arguments to a Sphinx container

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'm declaring a custom environment in the `preamble` of `conf.py` which takes 6 arguments

```
% REQUIREMENT STYLE/FORMAT
\newenvironment{sphinxclasscustomizedrequirement}[6]{
    \rule{15cm}{1pt}\\ 
    \fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont
    \color{red}
    ARG1 = #1\\[1ex]
    \color{black}
    ARG2 = #2\\[1ex]
    ARG3 = #3\\[1ex]
    ARG4 = #4\\[1ex]
    ARG5 = #5\\[1ex]
    \rule{15cm}{1pt}\\
}{}
```

I wrap some blocks into this environment using a `container` directive

```
.. container:: customizedrequirement
    
    HELLO WORLD THIS IS A TEST
```

However, I cannot figure out how to specify the 6 arguments of this environment.

I want to generate this LaTeX code

```
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{customizedrequirement}{123456}{LOREM}{IPSUM}{DOLOR}{SIT}
\sphinxAtStartPar
HELLO WORLD THIS IS A TEST
\end{sphinxuseclass}
```

But I can't figure out how to do that in `rst`.

If I specify the arguments like in `code-block`

```
.. container:: customizedrequirement
    :a: A
    :b: B
    :c: C
    :d: DEBUG
    
    HELLO WORLD THIS IS A TEST
```

Then it generates this

```
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{customizedrequirement}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{a}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{a}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{b}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{b}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{c}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{c}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{d}
\begin{sphinxuseclass}{debug}
\sphinxAtStartPar
HELLO WORLD THIS IS A TEST

\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
\end{sphinxuseclass}
```

How do I generate a call to my environment with the specified arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is writing a custom extension, because I could not get it to work out of the box, without an extension.

```
class Requirement(Directive):

    has_content = True

    option_spec = {
        'id': directives.unchanged_required,
        'source': directives.unchanged,
        'allocation': directives.unchanged_required,
        'safety': directives.unchanged_required,
    }


    def run(self):
        paragraph_node = nodes.paragraph()
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, paragraph_node)

        req_id = self.options.get('id', 'undefined')
        source = self.options.get('source', 'None (derived requirement)')
        allocation = self.options.get('allocation', 'undefined')
        safety = self.options.get('safety', 'undefined')       
        arguments = f'{{{req_id}}}{{{source}}}{{{allocation}}}{{{safety}}}'.replace('_','\_')
        
        latex_prefix = nodes.raw('', '\\begin{customizedrequirement}' + arguments, format='latex')
        latex_suffix = nodes.raw('', '\end{customizedrequirement}', format='latex')
        return [latex_prefix, paragraph_node, latex_suffix]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive("requirement", Requirement)

    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

This is the way I call the extension in `.rst`

```
.. requirement::
    :id: ABCDE
    :source: req_1
    :allocation: team1
    :safety: high

    This is the textual content
```

Finally, it generates the LaTeX I want :

```
\begin{customizedrequirement}{ABCDE}{req_1}{team1}{high}
\sphinxAtStartPar
\sphinxAtStartPar
This is the textual content


\end{customizedrequirement}
```

Don't forget to declare the style `customizedrequirement` to your `preamble` :

```
latex_elements = {
  'preamble': r'''
% REQUIREMENT STYLE/FORMAT
\newenvironment{customizedrequirement}[5]{
    \rule{15cm}{1pt}\\ 
    \small
    \color{red}
    #1\\[1ex]
    \color{black}
    SOURCE=#2\\[1ex]
    ALLOCATION=#3\\[1ex]
    SAFETY=#4\\[1ex]
}{
\rule{15cm}{1pt}\\
}
'''
}
```